# Return type of multi-valued Entity properties

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using App Engine's Datastore entities in my current project, and I have a multi-valued property for one of the entities. Now, my question is simple, if I store `String` objects as the values in the multi-value property by passing a `String` `ArrayList` as the value in the `setProperty("myPropertyName", myArrayList)` of my entity, what object will I receive when I run the following:

```
myEntity.getProperty("myPropertyName");
```

From my observation it doesn't seem to return an `ArrayList`, even though `ArrayList` is a `Collection` and, according to the documentation, `getProperty()` returns a `Collection` object.

Comment: You might consider storing the array as a JSON string, and encode/decode it using json-simple https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ or gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: I thought of doing that as a last resort, but since App Engine provides multi-valued properties why not use it. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of supported types can be found here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types.

Strongly consider using a JSON string as GAEfan suggested.

Edit:
According to the OP's comment below, you can store and get multiple values in the datastore as follows:

```
myEntity.setProperty("myPropertyName", myArrayListOfStrings)
List<String> myValues = myEntity.getProperty("myValueName");
```

Comment: I can't answer my question because I don't have enough reputations I'll answer it here. I figured it out. You can extract multi-valued properties as a List<supportedType>. Here is how I used it in my code:

  List<String> myValues = myEntity.getProperty("myValueName");

Given that you set the property value as a List of a supported type like this, setProperty("myPropertyName", myArrayListOfStrings), you can then get a List object with the values.